# How to aggregate multiple columns to sets in one pass through the rows

Tags: pandas, group-by, listagg

Given dataframe:

```
   a  b  c
  G1  1  6
  G1  2  7
  G2  1  7
  G2  3  8
  G2  4  9
  G3  5  9
```

I would like to aggregate the rows into:

```
            b          c
a                       
G1     {1, 2}     {6, 7}
G2  {1, 3, 4}  {8, 9, 7}
G3        {5}        {9}
```

One of the ways to arrive at this is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'a':['G1','G1','G2','G2','G2','G3'], 'b':[1,2,1,3,4,5], 'c':[6,7,7,8,9,9]})
df_agg1 = df.groupby ('a')['b'].apply (set)
df_agg2 = df.groupby ('a')['c'].apply (set)
pd.concat ([df_agg1, df_agg2], axis = 1)
```

However, for each additional column, this will require a separate pass through the rows.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use groupby.agg:

```
df.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: set(x))
Out: 
            b          c
a                       
G1     {1, 2}     {6, 7}
G2  {1, 3, 4}  {8, 9, 7}
G3        {5}        {9}
```